# How can I disable a button temporarily?

Tags: javascript

I have a button that increments the value in a textbox. Every time this value changes, there is an event that runs some code. However, this textbox value gets accessed by the event thread multiple times during the execution. How can I ensure that a second button click will not throw off the calculations?

Answer (score 2):

To enable and disable buttons.

to enable,

`document.getElementById("yourButtonId").disabled = false;`

to disable,

`document.getElementById("yourButtonId").disabled = true;`

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can do this:

```
// Set it to true
$("input").prop("disabled", true);
// Set it to false
$("input").prop("disabled", false);
```

I believe for older versions of jQuery, only this will work:

```
// To disable
$("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
// To enable
$("input").removeAttr("disabled");
```